# Generating "legal" keyframes for moving actor

Tags: ros, collision, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello Gazebo wizards!

I need some help with a gazebo plugin that generates random walk paths for a moving actor. How can I check if the generated path collides with objects in the world? It does not have to be real-time but pre-generated.

I followed the [animated actor guide](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=actor&cat=build_robot) to set up a box that can move around in a Gazebo world.

My problem is that there are objects in the world defined in the .world file that the actor collides and goes into.

I have this function to take the current position and return a random point in its circle area.

```
ignition::math::Vector3d generate_nextWaypoint(ignition::math::Vector3d curr_pos){
        int radius = 15;
        double u = ignition::math::Rand::DblUniform();
        double v = ignition::math::Rand::DblUniform();
        double w = radius * sqrt(u);
        double t = 2 * M_PI * v;
        double x0 = w * cos(t);
        double y0 = w * sin(t);
        double x_new = curr_pos.X() + x0;
        double y_new = curr_pos.Y() + y0;
        ignition::math::Vector3d new_position = ignition::math::Vector3d(x_new, y_new, curr_pos.Z());
        return new_position;
    }
```

how can I do a legal check so that the positions dont overlap with an object in the world?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26131/generating-%22legal%22-keyframes-for-moving-actor/) by [Magnus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/37136/magnus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

First save a pointer to the world at plugin load time.

```
void ActorPlugin::Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
{
  ...
  this->world = this->actor->GetWorld();
  ...
}
```

then I save my own model to an array of ignored models

```
this->ignoreModels.push_back(this->model->GetName());
```

Finally, when I have a generated waypoint, I can use this function to check it against models in the world

```
bool collisionFree(ignition::math::Vector3d &_pos, double radius)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->world->ModelCount(); ++i)
        {
            physics::ModelPtr worldObj = this->world->ModelByIndex(i);
            if (std::find(this->ignoreModels.begin(), this->ignoreModels.end(),
                          worldObj->GetName()) == this->ignoreModels.end())
            {
                ignition::math::Vector3d offset = worldObj->WorldPose().Pos() -
                                                  this->model->WorldPose().Pos();
                double modelDist = offset.Length();
                return modelDist > radius;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [Magnus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/37136/magnus/) with karma: 1 on 2020-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0